# Dialog progress bar for unsquashfs

Tags: dialog, squashfs

Part of my `dialog`-based program involves running unsquashfs on a file to extract it to a directory. I'm trying to make a progress bar for this operation to show its progress using the `--gauge` option. What I've tried is this:

```
unsquashfs -f -q -d extract_directory filesystem.squashfs | dialog --title "Progress" --gauge "Unsquashing filesystem..." 7 60
```

I've also tried unsquashfs with other options like `-i` and `-n`, and none of them seem to work. The progress bar does display, but it is always stuck at 0%. Is it possible to make it work? I don't mind using hacky workarounds if they are needed.

Comment: well `-n` disables the progress bar, so that's not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be that easy: `dialog --gauge` expects the percentages from stdin, as one number per line.

However, `unsquashfs` doesn't have that kind of output! It uses console control characters to update its progress bar, probably (at least it doesn't link against libncurses).

The important part is line 145 in `progressbar.c` in the squashfs-tools source code:

```
    printf("\r[");
…
    printf(" %3d%%", percentage);
```

The control character `\r` jumps to the beginning of the current line, then that line is overwritten with the progress bar, then the percentage is finally printed.

so you'll *probably* need something like

```bsh
unsquashfs linux.squash | tr $'\r' $'\n' | sed -ne 's/^.* \([[:digit:]]*\)\%$/\1/p' | dialog --gauge
```

**but** I doubt it will work. Most probably, there will be buffering, and all your percentages will appear at once (try without the `| dialog --gauge`).

Honestly, the progressbar of unsquashfs does work. Simply show that instead of a dialog showing the same?

Other than that, there's things like libraries which can uncompress squashfs, and I guess you could use these to build your own program that outputs percentages instead of anything else. Or, you could add a command line switch to `mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs`'s source code and make them do that – probably the easiest solution here.